# Adjust Image path in GUI app in Java using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have a java app that I have been developing using the NetBeans IDE.  I want to add an image to my gui with a variable path.  The number of different options that this path can be will be populated from a database and it is quite a large number so I do not want to import all of these images into my Netbeans application.

The code I have for my image:

```
jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

jLabel9.setIcon(new     
javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/defaultportrait.png"))); // NOI18N

jLabel9.setText("jLabel9");

desktopPane.add(jLabel9);
jLabel9.setBounds(520, 60, 170, 190);
```

I would like to have it so when I hit a button on my gui that the path for the image source is changed and the image is redrawn on my GUI.

Example:

```
private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     AdjustPictureSource;
     RedrawImage;

}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this.

Also, my apologies in advance, I am still quite a newbie in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `repaint()` calls the `paintComponent (Graphics g)` method, which does the redrawing for you.  Every GUI has an instance of this method by default, and you can override it if you want things painted differently.  Generally, if you don't want to draw lines, shapes, or text on top of the GUI, you shouldn't need to override it.

As for changing the path of the picture, you need to add listeners to GUI objects (such as buttons) to get them to do anything in Java.  In the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` method, you can put the code necessary to fetch the new URL.  For example, you could create a new `ImageIcon` and call the `setIcon` method of `jLabel9`.

As a side point, it's generally better to `import` classes you are using multiple times (such as `JLabel`, `ImageIcon`, etc.)

Edit: More complete example, using an anonymous inner class:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Press Here!");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        jLabel9.setIcon(new ImageIcon("newPath"));
    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call repaint, as setIcon is a bound property, meaning that it will cause a repaint automatically...